# Calling Set on a Firebase Database Reference Causes the Webpage to Hang

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using React and Node to build an web-based interface to modify data in a Firebase database.  I've previously used the Firebase Web SDK in this app to load data from the database, but I've encountered a strange issue with saving a user's changes.  When I call `set` on a database reference (i.e. `firebase.database().ref('/path/to/object').set({abc: 'xyz'})`), the webpage hangs.  Oddly enough, the changes are saved to the database, but the callbacks specified with `then` are never called (depending on the browser, a `This page is slowing down your browser` message appears).  I'm certain that the issue is related to `set` as removing the call removes the hang (see `save()` in my code below).

---

```
import React from 'react'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
// additional (unrelated) imports

export default class Editor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            savingModal: false,
            errorModal: false,
            cancelModal: false,
            errors: []
        }
    }

    save() {
        // this.form is a Reactstrap Form
        // validate is a function that returns an array of strings
        var errors;
        // validate the form, show the errors if any
        if ((errors = this.form.validate()) && errors.length > 0)
            this.setState({errorModal: true, errors: errors})
        else {
            // collect is a function that returns an object with the data that the user entered
            var x = this.form.collect()
            // getEditorInfo is a function that returns info such as the type of object being edited
            var info = this.getEditorInfo()
            firebase.database().ref(`/${info.category}/${x.id}/`).set(x).then(() => {
                this.closeEditor()
            }, e => {
                alert(`An unexpected error occurred:\n${e}`)
            })
            this.setState({savingModal: true})
        }
    }

    // closes the window or redirects to /
    closeEditor() {
        if (window.opener) 
            window.close()
        else 
            window.location.href = '/'
    }

    render() {
        // BasicModal is a custom component that renders a Reactstrap Modal
        // IndeterminateModal is a custom component that renders a Reactstrap Modal with only a Progress element
        // EditorToolbar and EditorForm are custom components that render the UI of the page (I don't think they're relevant to the issue)
        var info = this.getEditorInfo()
        if (!info) 
            return <BasicModal isOpen={true} onPrimary={this.closeEditor} primary="Close" header="Invalid Request" body="ERROR: The request is invalid."/>
        else
            return <div>
                <EditorToolbar onSave={this.save.bind(this)} onCancel={() => this.setState({cancelModal: true})}/>
                <EditorForm ref={f => this.form = f}/>
                <BasicModal toggle={() => this.setState({cancelModal: !this.state.cancelModal})} isOpen={this.state.cancelModal} header="Unsaved Changes" body={<p>If you close this window, your changes will not be saved.<br/>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>} primary="Close Anyway" primaryColor="danger" secondary="Go Back" onPrimary={this.closeEditor}/>
                <IndeterminateModal style={{
                                top: '50%',
                                transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
                }} isOpen={this.state.savingModal} progressColor="primary" progressText="Processing..."/>
                <BasicModal toggle={() => this.setState({errorModal: false, errors: []})} isOpen={this.state.errorModal} header="Validation Error" body={<div><p>Please resolve the following errors:<br/></p><ul>{(this.state.errors || []).map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>)}</ul></div>} primary="Dismiss" primaryColor="primary"/>
            </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1/8/2018**

I came across [this article](http://debuggable.com/posts/run-intense-js-without-freezing-the-browser:480f4dd6-f864-4f72-ae16-41cccbdd56cb) today and I decided to try a new solution involving JavaScript's `setTimeout` method.  In my situation, the freeze occurred after calling `this.setState` in my app then calling `firebase.database().ref(path).set(data)`.  I suspect the freezing issue was caused by this.  I guess JavaScript couldn't handle the state change and Firebase operation all at once.  **This new solution is functional, more secure, faster, and simpler.**  Take a look:

```
// to perform your desired Firebase operation:
var timeout = 50 // give JS some time (e.g. 50ms) to finish other operations first
setTimeout(() => firebase.database().ref(path).set(data).then(
    () => {/* ... */},
    error => {/* ... */}),
timeout)
```

---

**OLD SOLUTION**

<del>I ended up finding a solution.  I'm sure it could be improved, but it works.</del>  I used the Web Workers API to run my Firebase code.

---

1. Create a new JavaScript file in your `public` folder (Node.js)
2. Download a copy of the Firebase web SDK source and place it in `public`
3. I chose to communicate with my `Worker` with `postMessage`

---

`FirebaseWorker.js`

```
self.onmessage = event => {
    importScripts('./firebase.js') // import the local Firebase script
    firebase.initializeApp({/* your config */})
    const promise = p => p.then(
        () => self.postMessage({error: null}),
         e => self.postMessage({error: e})
    const doWork = () => {
        switch (event.data.action) {
            case 'get':
                promise(firebase.database().ref(event.data.path).once('value'))
                break;
            case 'set':
                promise(firebase.database().ref(event.data.path).set(event.data.data))
                break;
            case 'update':
                promise(firebase.database().ref(event.data.path).update(event.data.data))
                break;
            case 'remove':
                promise(firebase.database().ref(event.data.path).remove())
                break;
        }
    }
    if (!firebase.auth().currentUser)
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(event.data.email, event.data.password).then(() => doWork())
    else
        doWork()
}
```

---

To use the Worker:

```
var worker = new Worker('FirebaseWorker.js')
worker.onmessage = event => {
    if (event.data.error)
        alert(event.data.error)
    // ...
}
worker.postMessage({
    data: {/* your data (required if set or update is used) */},
    path: '/path/to/reference',
    action: 'get, set, update, or remove',
    email: 'someone@example.com',
    password: 'password123'
})
```